# Prometheus remote write recivers. How to stop recieving fake metrics?

Tags: prometheus, fluent-bit, kube-prometheus-stack

I know Prometheus works like a pull-based mechanism but we have to push metrics via fluent-bit. When fluent-bit stops sending metrics to Prometheus API, Prometheus receives fake metrics for 5 minutes. Fake metrics are the same as the last received ones.

Is there a cache-like mechanism for remote_write_receiver? How to avoid it?

- Prometheus is installed with helm chart with the following config.

```
...
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    enableAdminAPI: true
    enableFeatures:
     - remote-write-receiver
    enableRemoteWriteReceiver: true
...
```

- fluent-bit config is the following

```
    [INPUT]
        name prometheus_scrape
        tag  collect_logs
        host localhost
        port 9103
        metrics_path /metrics
        scrape_interval 60s
    [OUTPUT]
        name prometheus_remote_write
        match collect_logs
        host myhost.com
        port 443
        uri /api/v1/write
        tls on
        tls.verify off
```

[image]

Comment: What you call "fake metrics" are in fact your real metrics. They are returned by prometheus intentionally, as a mechanism to deal with metrics scraped at different, but close enough time. Read more about [staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness)

Comment: And this mechanism not working as intended is one of the reasons it's explicitly advised against of trying to use Prometheus in push based manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, we can not avoid these metrics.

Comment: I will try to set `prometheus.prometheusSpec.lookbackDelta` as 30s.

Comment: edit: `prometheus.prometheusSpec.query.lookbackDelta`